# "Vehicle-model design" or "vehicle model-design"

Tags: hyphenation

Which is the correct way to use the hyphen?

a) Vehicle-model design
b) Vehicle model-design

From experience, option b) seems accurate as it can be replaced with "design of vehicle model."

Comment: I think a, because—same reason that you have for b.

Comment: Vehicle-model design would be correct if you are designing a "model" in the sense of a new type or variant of vehicle. Vehicle model-design might be  read as  you were designing a "model" in the sense of a reduced scale replica.

Comment: I'd look for an alternative to both.  I can't help you with that without a whole sentence and maybe some context.

Comment: Can you provide some context, please? 'Vehicle design' alone is clear.

In ordinary English, 'vehicle-model design' works, but seems to add nothing to 'Vehicle design'. What difference do you see? 

'Vehicle model-design' is so much less likely to work in every-day English, I suggest it's down to you to explain how it could be useful. How, please?

Comment: What's wrong with saying "design of vehicle models," which is much more comprehensible than either of your two suggestions and seems to be what you want from your comment.

Answer (score 1):

"Vehicle model" is correct, since it consists of the noun "vehicle" modifying the noun "model."

Likewise, "model design" is correct, since it consists of the noun "model" modifying the noun "design."

Nothing stops such modifiers from having modifiers of their own. So you can freely combine them with no hyphens, giving you **vehicle model design.**

Comment: Is there any chance you could provide me with a reference for this?

Comment: @ananta [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) talks about "recursive noun adjuncts," giving the example "chicken soup bowl."